# What can I do to resolve this error code isssue?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, prompt

Use the prompt() method to ask the user what the maximum number should be. The prompt should be in a loop with validation as demonstrated previously in the course making sure that the inputted value is a positive number. If the user inputs a decimal, simply round it.

When a valid number is inputted, change the content of the instructions to specify guesses between 1 and N.

When the user presses the guess button, validate the input:

If the guess is not a number, display a message: "That is not a number!"
If the guess is out of range (1 to N), display a message: "That number is not in range, try again."
Using an array, keep track of each guess by the user. When the user wins the game by guessing correctly, add the number of guesses and the list of guesses to the victory message. For example:

"You got it! It took you 5 tries and your guesses were 3, 14, 7, 9, 5"

Do not count invalid guesses (not numbers or out of range).

Since you are tracking the guesses, add validation to check if a number has already been guessed. If it has, display a message and do not count it as a guess.

HTML File:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <title>Higher - Lower</title>

    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
            <h1>Higher Lower</h1>
            <p>Guess a number between 1 and <span class="max-number">N</span></p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 cold-md-6">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Your guess:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="userInput" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick= "do_guess()">Guess</button>
                     </form>
                </div>
             </div>
             <p id="message"></p>
        </div>
        <script src="HigherLowerEnhanced.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

JavaScript File:

```
let maxNumber;

// use an infinite loop that continues until a users input is validated
while (true) {

    maxNumber = prompt("What should the maximum number be?");

        // check if the user input is actually a number
        if (isNaN(maxNumber)) {

            // keeps the loop going until input is validated
            continue;
        }
    
    // check if the number is a decimal
    if (!Number.isInteger(maxNumber)) {
        // function that rounds numbers
        maxNumber = Math.round(maxNumber);
    }
    

    if (maxNumber < 1) {
        console.log("Please Enter number more than 0");

        continue;
    }

    // function to set the spans value to the input number
    const maxNumberSpan = document.querySelector('.max-number');
    maxNumberSpan.innerHTML = maxNumber;

    break;
    }

// generate random number between 1 and infinite
let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNumber) + 1;

// function stores users guesses
const inputArray = [];

document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    // prevents page from refreshing after you click submit
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // call do_guess() function on click
    do_guess();
});

// do_guess function
function do_guess() { 

    // get message div
    let message = document.getElementById("message"); 

    // get input value
    let guess = Number(document.getElementById("guess").value); 

    // if input is not a number
    if (isNaN(guess)) { 
        message.innerHTML = "This is not a number"; 

    // return function (so that user can submit another number)
    return; 
}
    // if number is out of range
    if (guess < 1 || guess > maxNumber) { 

        // show this message
        message.innerHTML = "That number is not in range, try again"; 

        // return function
        return; 
    }

    // indexOf() function finds guess in inputArray
    if (inputArray.indexOf(guess) != -1) {

        // when the guessed number is not found in the array it will return -1
        message.innerHTML = "You already have tried this number";
        return;
    }

    // now we have checked validation of input push guessed number on array
    inputArray.push(guess); 

    // if input is equal to num
    if (guess == num) { 
        message.innerHTML = "You got it! It took you " + inputArray.length + " tries and your guesses were " + inputArray.toString();
        
    }

    // if guess is more
    else if (guess > num) { 
        message.innerHTML = "No, try a lower number.";
        
    }

    // if guessed number is less
    else { 
        message.innerHTML = "No, try a higher number.";
    }
}
```

Error:

```
[Running] node "/Users/tonyjones/Desktop/HigherLowerEnhanced/HigherLowerEnhanced.js"
/Users/tonyjones/Desktop/HigherLowerEnhanced/HigherLowerEnhanced.js:6
        maxNumber = prompt("What should the maximum number be?");
        ^

ReferenceError: prompt is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tonyjones/Desktop/HigherLowerEnhanced/HigherLowerEnhanced.js:6:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.12.1

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.324 seconds
```

Comment: You are running this in Node.js instead of the browser. Don't run it in Node.js and run it in the browser, if that's what you actually want.

Comment: I've been assigned to run this along with other projects that are very similar for intro learning purposes and the other projects worked fine. How exactly can I get it to run through the browser? When I try to run and debug, the only options to come up are node.js and python. After I open the HTML file in a default browser, only the first part of what I'm trying to do works, the rest doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

- You are trying to use `prompt`. Node.js does not provide a native `prompt` function. Web browsers do.
- Ditto the `document` object.
- You have an HTML document. Node.js does not centre on HTML documents. Web browsers do.

Run your code in a web browser instead of in Node.js.

Comment: I've been assigned to run this along with other projects that are very similar for intro learning purposes and the other projects worked fine. How exactly can I get it to run through the browser? When I try to run and debug, the only options to come up are node.js and python. After I open the HTML file in a default browser, only the first part of what I'm trying to do works, the rest doesn't.

Comment: To get it to run in the browser, load the HTML document into a browser. To debug it in a browser use a query like [this one](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=how+to+debug+javascript+in+a+webpage).

Comment: To configure your IDE to run it in a browser try a query like [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=debug+javascript+in+browser+with+INSERT+NAME+OF+IDE+HERE&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALiCzsYWr0bPwLMlYTRjskRwubNblksl2g%3A1669317577105&ei=ycN_Y5iHBonWgQai87qQAw&ved=0ahUKEwjYj83JxMf7AhUJa8AKHaK5DjIQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=debug+javascript+in+browser+with+INSERT+NAME+OF+IDE+HERE). Please read [ask]. We have no idea what "the first part" and "the rest" are.